# Is C# a=b=c; equal to b=c; a=c; whereas C++ is b=c; a=b;?

Tags: c#

In another words, C# operator= will return the right value, isn't it? But C++ conventionally returns left value, right?

Comment: I avoid this syntax precisely for this reason - it should be immediately obvious what your code does.

Comment: @Kragen: 1) It doesn't happen like that.  2) Even it did, what different behavior could *possibly* result?

Comment: @Kirk Dunno, but `a = c; b = c;` (when written on two lines) avoids even having to think about *any* possible ambiguity *and* makes it obvious that there are two assigments.

Comment: @Kragen, presumably two `=` suggests two assignments?  (and for what it's worth, the comparison should be with `b = c; a = b`.

Comment: @Kirk What if A, B and C are **all** proprties and what if they are also different types with implictly overided casts - what getters / setters are called and what casts are invoked?  I'm not saying that you can't work it out (or even that its difficult), just that *two simple assignments shouldn't involve this sort of mental overhead*.  There are already 4 different answers to this question (one of which is wrong!)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, the result of the assignment expression is the value assigned, *not* the expression on the right. So consider this:

```
    byte a;
    int b;
    byte c = 10;

    a = b = c; // Fails to compile
```

This fails to compile because although `b = c` is valid, it's an expression of type `int`, which then can't be assigned to `a` which is of type `byte`.

From the C# 4 language spec, section 7.17.1:

> The result of a simple assignment expression is the value assigned to the left operand. The result has the same type as the left operand and is always classified as a value.

EDIT: Here's proof that it's the value which was assigned to `b` which is used, *not* the value of `c`:

```
using System;

class ACType
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator BType(ACType ac)
    {
        return new BType { Value = ac.Value / 2 };
    }
}

class BType
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator ACType(BType b)
    {
        return new ACType { Value = b.Value / 2 };
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ACType a, c;
        BType b;

        c = new ACType { Value = 100 };
        a = b = c;

        Console.WriteLine(a.Value); // Prints 25
    }
}
```

The `a = b = c;` statement is equivalent to:

```
BType tmp = c;
b = tmp;
a = tmp;
```

So the value of `b` isn't *read* afterwards (it's not equivalent to `b = c; a = b;`) - so if `b` were actually a property, the behaviour of the property would be irrelevant other than for side-effects. It's *whatever value was used in the assignment to `b`* which is also used in the assignment to `a`.

In this case, the assignment to `b` requires a conversion from `ACType` to `BType` which creates a `BType` with Value=50. The assignment to `a` then requires a conversion from `BType` to `ACType`, which creates an `ACType` with Value=25.

Comment: ...although `a = b` is valid... You mean `b = a`?

Comment: @Hemant: Sorry, it was broken. Fixed - and reversed to make it more like the original.

Comment: The interesting thing about this is the overall value of the expression `a = b = c` may look nothing at all like the value of *any* of the variables here, which may not at all be equal. Part of this I knew, part of this you helped me learn, and most of it I hope to never ever really have to consider in my coding activities.

Comment: @Anthony: It's funny how this was today, and yesterday had another compound assignment question which wasn't as simple as it sounded: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577140/why-does-swapping-values-with-xor-fail-when-using-this-compound-form

Comment: I wonder why it is so complex, and the result of the assignment is not the left operand. Such behaviour would be "symmetric" to function chain calling.

Comment: @macias: I don't think it would be terribly obvious for the property to be read again, to be honest. I would avoid code like this to start with though :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I rephrase -- for me such equivalent is (seriously) obvious -- b = c; a = b; (I refer to your last example). Why this is obvious for me? Because methods work this way, the last result is passed to next call as "this". After reading your explanation (thank you!) I simply gave up using assignment chaining, because of the principle of least surprise.

Answer (score 9):

No, it works the same in both languagues:  `a = b = c;` works like this: `a = (b = c);`.  The assignment operator works right-to-left, and the value returned is the result of the assignment, which is the left-hand-side.  So conceptually, `a = b = c;` is the same as:  `b = c; a = b;`.

For C#, the assignment operators and the conditional operator (?:) are right-associative, meaning that operations are performed from right to left. For example, x = y = z is evaluated as x = (y = z).  ([Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28VS.71%29.aspx))

Same for C++ ([Source](http://cppreference.com/wiki/language/operator_precedence))

Comment: I know the right operator= will be evaluated at first definitely in either C# or C++. My question actually is, for a = (b = c), which value will be used assign to 'a'? 'b' or 'c'?

Comment: @Bob L: The value that was used to assign to `b`. I'm coming up with an example now.

Comment: you are contradicting yourself. In C# b will NOT be  assigned to a! And you said it works the same in both languages (it is not true). "a = b = c; is the same as: b = c; a = b;" In C# it is not.

Answer (score 3):

A useful tidbit about the semantics of `a = b = c` is that `a` will indeed receive the same value (*normally* `c`*) that was *assigned* to `b`, the *present* value of `b` is not a factor.

Yes, that could be considered surprising. Consider the example:

```
class Foo
{
    private int _bar;
    public int Bar
    {
        get { return _bar; }
        set { _bar = value + 1; }
    }
}

...

Foo foo = new Foo();
int a, c;
c = 4;

a = foo.Bar = c; // is 'a' 4 or 5?
```

If the value passed through `foo.Bar` and the mutation follows into `a`, then `a` would be 5. However, that is not what happens. `a` and `foo.Bar` receive the same value, `a` does not receive the mutation from `foo.Bar`. It's not directly your question, but it's interesting enough to post considering some of the comments.

---

*Jon Skeet had an interesting observation about types that are implicitly convertible to one another but have data loss/modification in the conversion. In this case, the value may very well *not* be the original value of `c`, but the converted value, which may be different.

Comment: Yes. I encountered something similar as your example though I used Indexer. The result of program doubts me so I posted this question. I am still learning C#, now I believe C#'s property and indexer are exceptions of returning left value of operator= rule...

Comment: @Bob, consider the text posted in Jon Skeet's answer. *"The result of a simple assignment expression is the value **assigned** to the left operand."* It's not the value *of* the left operand, as that could have already mutated (as demonstrated above) and produce an unexpected result.

Comment: It won't always be the same value as `c`. Imagine two types which have implicit conversions to each other, but lose data, where `a` and `c` are one type, and `b` is the other type. The conversion from the type of `c` to the type of `b` would be performed, then the conversion back to the type of `a` would be performed.

Comment: @Jon, interesting point. I'll indeed test that scenario where a data loss occurs prior to the assignment.

Comment: @Jon... wow, yeah, just tested that. Might have a nightmare about this one.

Comment: @Anthony: I've just posted a short but complete program in my answer. Is that roughly what you tested? Hopefully my explanation at the bottom covers your property part too.

Comment: @Jon, yes, that's basically what I did, using classes *and* structs to cover my bases.