# XOR Steps to C# Interview code

Tags: c#, xor, bitwise-xor

I came upon this interview question through a link from LinkedIn and I know what an XOR does, but at the same time I am not comfortable with bit shifting and stuff like that, if I don't have to do it I try not to make things overly complicated for myself.

But I would really like to understand more about how these things work in the case that I find a good use case in the future.

> ## Predict the output for the below program
>
> ```
> public class Program
> {
>     public static void Main(string[] args)
>     {
>         int x = 1975;
>         int y = 2015;
>         x ^= y ^= x ^= y;
>         Console.WriteLine("x = " + x + "; y = " + y);
>     }
> }
> ```

it gives the output

> x = 0;Y=1975

Can someone please break this into steps to explain what exactly is going on in this line of code? order of assignment, etc?

> ```
> x ^= y ^= x ^= y;
> ```

Comment: I reopened the question, because the more interesting point here is not the xor, but the order of execution, meaning which values are actually xored.

Comment: I wouldn't be comfortable with such as interview question because of `x ^= y ^= x ^= y` being completely unreadable. A correct answer may indicate you are a nerd, but definitely not you are a good developer.

Comment: But could be treated as dupe of [Why does swapping values with XOR fail when using this compound form?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5577140/15498)

Comment: that is exactly what I was looking for @Damien_The_Unbeliever, thank you